# Interface method with interface parameter, where implementations have their own class as parameter

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, methods, interface

Suppose that I have the following interface:

```
interface IShape
{
    bool Intersect(IShape shape);
}
```

Then I want the following concrete implementations:

```
class Circle : IShape
{
    bool Intersect(Circle shape) {...}
}

class Rectangle : IShape
{
    bool Intersect(Rectangle shape) {...}
}
```

Is there any smart way to do this in C# without using generics? 
I.e any way that is not like this:

```
interface IShape<T> where T : IShape<T>
{
    bool Intersect(T shape);
}

class Circle : IShape<Circle>
{
    bool Intersect(Circle shape) {...}
}
```

Comment: Why do you not want to use generics?

Comment: At compile time, there is no way to express "A method that returns or takes a parameter of the same type as the declaring type" in C#. Your best option is to take an `IShape` in parameter and check the actual type at runtime, which also allows you to intersect with multiple shape types.

Comment: @Sweeper because if I use generics I think that there is no way to declare a generic `IShape`. I must declare an `IShape<Rectangle>` or `IShape<Circle>`, but I can't have an 'any' `IShape`.

Comment: @DadeKuma Suggested reading: https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/

Comment: @DadeKuma Let's suppose you _could_ do that without generics, and here I have a variable of type `IShape` named `x`. What type can I pass to `x.Intersect`? `IShape`? That would imply I can pass a `Circle` to it, which I can't if `x` is a `Rectangle` at runtime.

Comment: @vc74 that article describes perfectly my problem. Thank you.

Comment: @Sweeper You are right. That makes no sense. I was trying to find a way to have a "clean" way to do it, but the only way to do it with that design is to check the actual type at runtime.

Comment: Reason about the problem from the perspective of the *caller*, not the *implementer*.  Someone is going to call `Intersect`.  Show us what a typical caller's code looks like, indicating the compile-time types of the various expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To illustrate my comment:

```
interface IShape
{
    bool Intersect(IShape shape);
}

class Circle : IShape
{
    public bool Intersect(IShape shape)
    {
        switch (shape)
        {
            case Circle circle:
                // Circle / circle intersection
                break;

            case Rectangle rectangle:
                // Circle / rectangle intersection
                break;

            ....

            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Or use a totally different class to handle intersections, as in [Eric Lippert's article](https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use explicit interface implementations like this:

```
interface IShape
{
    bool Intersect(IShape shape);
}

class Circle : IShape
{
    bool IShape.Intersect(IShape shape) { return Intersect((Circle)shape); }
    public bool Intersect(Circle shape) { ... }
}
```

However, this makes your code very unsafe, because you could write something like this and still pass compilation:

```
IShape s = new Circle();
s.Intersect(new Rectangle());
```

The above will throw an exception at runtime.

Use this with caution.